# C# - Comparing/Replacing Text Using Two .txt Files

Tags: c#, regex, compare, text-files, replace

I want to take in a certain format of one text file. After the first file is loaded and reformatted, I want to open a second text file and check if the second file has any text matches with the first re-formatted file. Right now I am successfully reformatting the first text file to how I want it. The first (reformatted) text file looks like this:

```
    1       0010  12345              DEF, DEF-0320                  
    1       0020  ABC-00010G         ABC-A,1xx,10%,x1x,0603         
    1       0020A ABC-00010G         ABC-A,1xx,10%,x1x,0603         
    1       0030A ABC-00127G         ABC,4.7xx,10%,x1x,0805  
    .
    .
    .
```

I want to know how to take this file (above) and find the second column (0010, 0020, 0020A, 0030A, ...) and compare it/search for it in a second text file.  The format for the second text file will look something like this:

```
    10 BARE PCB
    20 T C40, C3112
    B D5, D45, D48
    30 B R25 
    .
    .
    .
```

Once I am able to find the match from the first file (0010, 0020, 0020A, 0030A) with the second file (10, 20, B, 30) I want to grab the lines after the 10, 20, B, 30 and replace the first files 0010, 0020, 0020A, 0030A with them. Also, if the number from the first one does not end with an "A" (ie, 0010) I want to put a "T" at the end of the new file. However, if it does end with an "A" (ie, 0030A) I want to put a "B" at the end of the file. Also, for every value in the second file that is in the format "C40" (or similar) I want to place on a new line if there is multiple (seperated by a ",") and copy the same information from the above line. This meaning it would look like this:

```
    1       AAAA BCD  12345              DEF, DEF-0320                 T
    1       C40       ABC-00010G         ABC-A,1xx,10%,x1x,0603        T
    1       C3112     ABC-00010G         ABC-A,1xx,10%,x1x,0603        T
    1       D5        ABC-00010G         ABC-A,1xx,20%,x1x,0603        B
    1       D45       ABC-00010G         ABC-A,1xx,20%,x1x,0603        B
    1       D48       ABC-00010G         ABC-A,1xx,20%,x1x,0603        B
    1       R25       ABC-00127G         ABC,4.7xx,100%,x1x,0805       B
```

General basis of my code:

- Open button: Opens a txt file.
- Save button: Saves the new formatted text file where ever I want to save it to.
- Clear button: Clears the text in all of the rich text boxes I use.
- OpenRefs button: Opens the second txt file used to compare with the first file.**

**I am also trying to get this button to output the final formatting of the text into the final rich text box.

Here is my current code.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

    namespace Formatter
    {
       public partial class Form : Form
       {
          // Create a OpenFileDialog to request a path and file name to open.
          OpenFileDialog openFile = new OpenFileDialog();
          OpenFileDialog openRefs = new OpenFileDialog();

          public Form()
          {
             InitializeComponent();
          }

          private void openButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
          {
             // Initialize the OpenFileDialog to specify the .txt extension as well as
             // its intial directory for the file.
             openFile.DefaultExt = "*.txt";
             openFile.Filter = ".txt Files|*.txt";
             openFile.InitialDirectory = "C:\\";
             openFile.RestoreDirectory = true;

             try
             {
                // Open the contents of the file into the originalTextRichTextBox.
                if (openFile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK && openFile.FileName.Length > 0)
                   originalTextRichTextBox.LoadFile(openFile.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);

                // Throws a FileNotFoundException otherwise.
                else
                   throw new FileNotFoundException();

                // Resets the formattedTextRichTextBox so multiple files aren't loaded on top of eachother.
                formattedTextRichTextBox.ResetText();

                foreach (string line in File.ReadAllLines(openFile.FileName))
                {
                   // Uses regular expressions to find a line that has, digit(s), space(s), digit(s) + letter(s),
                   // space(s), digit(s), space(s), any character (up to 25 times).
                   Match theMatch = Regex.Match(line, @"^[\.*\d]+\s+[\d\w]+\s+[\d\-\w*]+\s+.{25}");

                   if (theMatch.Success)
                   {
                      // Stores the matched value in string output.
                      string output = theMatch.Value;

                      // Sets the formattedTextRichTextBox to the string output.
                      formattedTextRichTextBox.AppendText(output);
                      formattedTextRichTextBox.AppendText("\n");
                   }
                }
             }

             // Catches an exception if the file was not opened.
             catch (Exception)
             {
                MessageBox.Show("There was not a specified file path.", "Path Not Found Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
             }
          }

          private void saveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
          {
             // Create a SaveFileDialog to request a path and file name to save.
             SaveFileDialog saveFile = new SaveFileDialog();

             // Initialize the SaveFileDialog to specify the .txt extension for the file.
             saveFile.DefaultExt = "*.txt";
             saveFile.Filter = ".txt Files|*.txt";
             saveFile.InitialDirectory = "C:\\";
             saveFile.RestoreDirectory = true;

             try
             {
                // Save the contents of the formattedTextRichTextBox into the file.
                if (saveFile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK && saveFile.FileName.Length > 0)
                   formattedTextRichTextBox.SaveFile(saveFile.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);

                // Throws a FileNotFoundException otherwise.
                else
                   throw new FileNotFoundException();
             }

             // Catches an exception if the file was not saved.
             catch (Exception)
             {
                MessageBox.Show("There was not a specified file path.", "Path Not Found Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
             }
          }

          private void clearButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
          {
             try
             {
                // Resets the text in all of the boxes.
                originalTextRichTextBox.ResetText();
                formattedTextRichTextBox.ResetText();
                refsTextRichTextBox.ResetText();
                finalTextRichTextBox.ResetText();
             }

             // Catches an exception if the either text box could not be cleared.
             catch (Exception)
             {
                MessageBox.Show("Could not clear the text.", "Clearing Text Box Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
             }
          }

          private void openRefsButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
          {
             // Initialize the OpenFileDialog to specify the .txt extension as well as
             // its intial directory for the file.
             openRefs.DefaultExt = "*.txt";
             openRefs.Filter = ".txt Files|*.txt";
             openRefs.InitialDirectory = "C:\\";
             openRefs.RestoreDirectory = true;

             try
             {
                // Open the contents of the file into the originalTextRichTextBox.
                if (openRefs.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK && openRefs.FileName.Length > 0)
                   refsTextRichTextBox.LoadFile(openRefs.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);

                // Throws a FileNotFoundException otherwise.
                else
                   throw new FileNotFoundException();


                // ********************************************
                // ******************************************** 
                // ********************************************
                // FROM HERE DOWN IS WHERE I NEED THE HELP! :)
                // ********************************************
                // ********************************************
                // ********************************************
                string[] refLines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(openRefs.FileName);

                foreach (string line in refLines)
                {
                   finalTextRichTextBox.AppendText(line + "\n");
                }

                try
                {
                   using (StreamReader readRefs = new StreamReader(openRefs.FileName))
                   {
                      originalTextRichTextBox.ResetText();

                      List<string> refFileLines = new List<string>();

                      while (!readRefs.EndOfStream)
                      {
                         refFileLines.Add(readRefs.ReadLine());
                      }

                      using (StreamReader readFile = new StreamReader(openFile.FileName))
                      {
                         List<string> fileLines = new List<string>();

                         while (!readFile.EndOfStream)
                         {
                            fileLines.Add(readFile.ReadLine());
                         }
                      }

                      refFileLines.Contains("");
                   }
                }

                catch (Exception)
                {
                   MessageBox.Show("Could not read file.", "Read File Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                }
             }

             // Catches an exception if the file was not opened.
             catch (Exception)
             {
                MessageBox.Show("There was not a specified file path.", "Path Not Found Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
             }
          }
       }
    }
```

I am getting a little lost on what to do. I was trying to take in each line and store it in a list of strings and once I had both files (open button and openrefs button) read into two sets of List I was going to use string.contains("some_string") but in the files the numbers could each time I open a different file. I am not sure how I would go about iterating properly though each item in each list to compare the strings (that can be different each 'session'). I was also going to concatinate them together and add the final result into another List and write it to the final rich text box. However, I am getting lost and am pretty new to C#. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Question: How can I compare these two text files, put them into a list properly, compare the two lists for values that are similar, replace the values in the first file with the following text from the matched values in the second file? If this is confusing, let me know!

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your columns are delimited with spaces, or some other character(s), using string.Split to make an array of columns.  Pick out the column you want and store it in a SortedList (column is both key and value), checking each time you add to ensure no duplicates are added.  Read your second file one line at a time, foreach on SortedList keys, and if string.Contains the key, flag the line as having one of the column values.

Comment: Okay so I am using the string.Split.. here is my code for that step. string[] finalText = refsTextRichTextBox.Text.Split(' ');
foreach (string line in finalText) { finalTextRichTextBox.AppendText(line + "\n");}  ---- This prints it out in the final rich text box with every value on a new line. However when I use my code: Match numberMatch = Regex.Match(finalTextRichTextBox.Text, @"^[\d]+"); originalTextRichTextBox.AppendText(numberMatch + "\n"); --- the print out only shows the number "10" a whole bunch of times on new lines. It seems to only be grabbing the first value line instead of all..?

Comment: What are you using the Regex.Match to try to accomplish?  I see no reason to use it for anything you're trying to do.  I've shown you how to do a basic column match.  What are your specific remaining questions?

Comment: I am using regex to only match the lines that have ONLY numbers.. when I split it, it looks like:
10
BARE
PCB
20
T
C40
B
...
But I want to grab the 10, 20, etc and then find those values in the first file. Once I find them in there, I want to grab the values that are in "C3" format (that is a letter and number(s) following) and use the string.contains on file one with the new regex that finds the "C3" formatted lines to replace the string.contains item. If that makes sense? I am new to C# and am not sure I understand exactly how to do what you said in your 'answer' text.

Comment: Don't use Regex for that. Take your column strings and either strip out all letters using foreach and a StringBuilder (adding digits only) or use something like int.TryParse to detect that it's a valid integer. Throw away column values that aren't the kind you want.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really get the formatting of your records because you say you are splitting with a space but your records won't split correctly on that.  If your file is a fixed length file then you can use .substring to pull data out.  If I am reading your question right I think you are going to want to read each line of the first file and add it the line into a hashset using the second column as a key and then the rest of the line as the value.  Then cycle through the second file and for each value in the line find the key it goes with and print the value from the key along with the value of the line you just read.  You can then find a spot to add a condition that if the key has an "A" or what not you also print a "T" at the end.  I think you should stay away from the regex because performance is generally lacking and I don't think it's what you need here.

```
     string strFileName = DisplayFile("Please Select File 1", ".txt", null);

      StreamReader srInput = File.OpenText(strFileName);

      Hashtable newHash = new Hashtable();

      while(srInput.Peek > -1)
      {
            string temp = srInput.ReadLine();
             string parts = temp.Split('//put delimiter here');

             newHash.Add(parts[1]//your key should be your second column                 value,parts              [2]//this is your value);

      }
```

//then read in your second file and test each line to see if it has a match in the first file.

```
     string strFileName2 = DisplayFile("Please Select File 2", ".txt", null);

     StreamReader srInput2 = File.OpenText(strFileName);

    while(srInput2.Peek > -1)
    {
   string temp2 = srInput.Readline();
   string[] parts2 = temp2.Split('delim');

   if(newHash.ContainsKey(parts[whichever is the column you want to check is]))
   {
         //then print to value to new file or list
         //newList.Add(parts[that were checked] + newHash[parts that were checked]);
    }
    }
```

something like that will work.

Comment: The file is not a fixed length unfortunately. :( I am pretty familiar with regex and not so much with coding in other ways which is also unfortunate! I am trying to learn though :). How would I store the first file into a hashset and use the second column as a key and the rest as a value? I am unfamiliar with this...